# Accessing ModalProps in react-bootstrap Modal to set size dynamically

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

sI'm currently migrating from react-bootstrap 0.32.1 to 1.0.0 - there are a lot of differences. :/

I am trying to set a Modal size based on a prop:

```
<Modal show={this.props.show} size={this.props.size} onHide={this.props.onHide}>
```

But I get this error now:
***Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"sm" | "lg" | "xl"'.***

I can see that the Modal has an interface in node_modules

```
export interface ModalProps extends TransitionCallbacks {
  size?: 'sm' | 'lg' | 'xl';
```

How do I access the ModalProps? Or cast the `this.props.size` as a ModalProps size?

Answer (score 0):

You can cast types with `as`

So this should work:

```
import { ModalProps } from "@thatPackage"

<Modal 
  show={this.props.show} 
  size={this.props.size as ModalProps.size} 
  onHide={this.props.onHide}
>{...}</Modal>
```

Where `@thatPackage` is of course the node_module you are using / Modal dep.

But beware that typecasting is overwriting typescript's inference. You need to make sure that you are really passing a `ModalProps.size` value. You components props should specify size also as `ModalProps.size`.

Comment: I added `import {ModalProps} from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';`

and updated Modal to:
`<Modal show={this.props.show} size={this.props.size as ModalProps["size"]} onHide={this.props.onHide}>`

also tried:
<Modal show={this.props.show} size={this.props.size as ModalProps.size} onHide={this.props.onHide}>


To my component .d.ts file I added:
```import ModalProps from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';

size?: ModalProps.size  (also tried: size?: ModalProps )
```
Nothing has worked.
I get an error
TS2304: Cannot find name 'ComponentProps'.

Comment: Well where do you mention in your code ComponentProps, maybe related or unrelated

Comment: Still can't figure this out:
`import ModalProps from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';`
`Modal size={(this.props.size || 'sm') as ModalProps['size']}`

I get this error:
TS2339: Property 'size' does not exist on type 'Modal<"div">'.

Comment: The props are not the default export https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/8ec39b187a871cfcecb8bdd1b6a5340111d2641d/src/Modal.tsx#L28

Try `import { ModalProps } from 'react-bootstrap/Modal'`